# Where can I find this snare drum sample?

Tags: electronic-music, production, dj, snare-drum

While producing a new track, the need arose to find a very specific one-shot snare drum sample. Unfortunately, [the sample I got](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3xoOa3SlgyEalV6R3pnTTNTbkk/view?usp=sharing) is polluted with an unwanted triangle sound, so I will need to find another one that sounds as similar as possible. It must have:

- low resonance or no resonance at all
- very sharp transient
- short duration of the overall sample (more "BUTZ!" instead of "Burrrrzz")
- spectral charateristic and development of spectrum as close as possible to the original.

Can anyone point me to a specific sample that gets close or knows where to look for it? Is this from a specific drum computer? I already thought this sound might be from a drum synth cause it's almost completely lacking reso. The source of the sample is an 80s disco track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally got the sound after hours of research: It's from an Oberheim DMX! Babäim!